# Using dplyr::recode on a dot

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

If have encountered a problem in R/dplyr when trying to use `recode` on a dot. I'm using R 3.6.3 and dplyr 0.8.5 This attempt

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- c("a", ",", ".")
recode(x, a = "A", "," = "comma", "." = "dot")
```

fails for the dot (works for "a" and ",") with error message

```
Error: Argument 2 must be named, not unnamed
```

Using back-ticks around the dot throws the same error. Escaping the dot does clear the error, but the dot is not recoded.

```
recode(x, a = "A", "," = "comma", "\\." = "dot")
[1] "A"     "comma" "."
```

Any ideas how to recode a dot?

Comment: `recode(x, !!!c(a = "A", "," = "comma", '.' = "dot"))` works fine, but I don't why it works hence I added as a comment.